# Would an index be efficient in this context?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have the table: `products` with the following columns (`productCode`, `productName`, `productDescription`, `quantityInStock`, `buyPrice`, `image`)

Would an index on `productName` for instance be useful when the following query is performed? `SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName=:productName`?

Answer (score 2):

For a query such as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE productName = :productName;
```

An index on `products(productName)` is strongly recommended.

Comment: How about indexing `buyPrice` for a query as `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY buyPrice` and `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY buyPrice DESC`? since indexes are sorted in ASC order by default I do consider it that would be efficient to do so.

Comment: Why not try and see what happens, you'll never modify your data through adding, modifying or removing indices

Comment: @codeDragon . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do for that query is to index productName.
Also, I would recommend not to select(*), but to select only the columns you actually need.

Also, if there are only few columns you need to select, or only one, you can even consider a covering index.

For example:

```
SELECT productName, buyPrice
FROM products
WHERE productName = 'test';
```

For the query above, I would add an index for products(productName, buyPrice). This will allow the database to use the index to both filter and retrieve the data, which should be very quick.

Regarding the other queries you mentioned in your comment above:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY buyPrice
```

I would index products(buyPrice) in this case - it doesn't matter if you order by ASC or DESC, as long as it's consistent in the query (all colums in the ORDER BY are either DESC or ASC).

Also, I would avoid select(*), and also consider adding LIMIT in these queries (do you actually need all the rows?).

Comment: Even if I need all the columns, still should I avoid `SELECT (*)` and list all the columns instead ?

Comment: In case you need all columns, replacing the SELECT(*) statement with an explicit list won't improve performance, but will definitely help with avoiding bugs. For example, what happens if in your code you rely on the fact you receive 5 columns as a result from the query and one year later you add 2 more columns to the table? If you state the column names explicitly, nothing will change. If you use SELECT(*), you suddenly get those 2 columns (which are unused by the code) and bad things can happen. If the answer above helped you, please consider accepting it as the question's answer :)